# Calling abstract function on boost thread, does not interrupt at interruption_point

Tags: multithreading, boost, mfc, abstract-class

I have created an abstract base class to allow for multiple implementation of a task, which can be called generically via MFC dialog. This task needs to be able to be interrupted if the user clicks cancel.

**abstract_dll.h:**

```
class abstract_dll
{
public:
    virtual void my_task(CFeedback *fb)=0;
}
```

Where `CFeedback` is an abstract class to control user feedback (ie. progress bar)

**concrete_dll.h:**

```
class concrete_dll 
{
    virtual void my_task(CFeedback *fb)
    {
        //do some work
        //step progress bar
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();

        //do some work
        //step progress bar
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
    }
}

extern "C" abstract_dll* get_class() { return new concrete_dll(); }
```

Now within the MFC Dialog I load the appropriate concrete_dll and initialize my `abstract_dll *dll = module->get_class();`

Then start a new `boost::thread` which calls the `dll->my_task(fb);`

Then when I call `thread.interrupt()`. The thread is never interrupted, and it never excepts at my interruption_points. I have traced the thread ID it is the same until we're in the concrete_dll implementation, then I just get 0x0000 for the thread id.

Any thoughts? PS. The code above is just pseudo code for what I have. My actual code compiles and runs, I just can't get it to interrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is here:

http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/01/55171.php

In short: you need to link to DLL version of boost:threads both in your project and DLL. Just put the:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL
```

before `<boost/thread.hpp>` inclusion (or in the project propeties)

BR

Comment: Thanks! We figured out the multiple data structures later in the day. But we didn't figure out the BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL, however we solved this by putting the interrupt in the CFeedBack so that it would come back to the main thread pool structure. Again, thanks.